# Nutritional Value / Beneficial Substances contained within Turmeric skin

Tags: juice, turmeric, antioxidant, herbs

Wikipedia [writes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turmeric) that turmeric is a plant of the ginger family, which is grown for its rhizomes. "It is native to southern Asia, requiring temperatures between 20 and 30 °C (68 and 86 °F) and a considerable amount of annual rainfall to thrive." You can use the rhizomes fresh, like you would use ginger; or you can use them boiled and dried.

I plan to use a juicer to juice some turmeric just for general health purposes (not for a sick person).

Some recipes, like [this one](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/golden-milk-turmeric-tea), recommend to process it unpeeled.

I'm just curious whether there is any nutritional value or beneficial substances (antioxidants, etc) in the skin part that could be good for human health?

Comment: Related: ["Does ginger have to be peeled? If so how?"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30305/does-ginger-have-to-be-peeled-if-so-how)

Comment: [Related chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57727/discussion-between-tealhill-and-gin99).

Comment: You said in the chat that you're from Asia, and in your country, many people like to peel the turmeric when serving it. Well, [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131017123147AAnk1Df) someone says you can eat the skin. Fine. Then what could you gain by peeling it? Maybe some slight time savings. This seems a trivial gain.

Comment: OK, so maybe do this: Just ignore what people in your country do. Instead, wash and scrub your turmeric well, then throw it into your juicer (with the peel still on). Does this sound like a good plan?